# Firefox 66: Tab reordering by dragging does not work anymore

Tags: firefox, tabbed-browsing

When I try to drag a tab to another location then a document dragging icon appears as shown below. I try to move it between other tabs but there is no upwards arrow appearing as before. No matter where I release the mouse button the tab will always move to a new window.

I only have unrelated plugins and themes which are: LiteFox *theme*, Quick locale switcher *extension*, Shockwave Flash *plugin*, Open H264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems Inc. *plugin*. That is all. I disabled them, did not help.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with Firefox 66.0.3 64bit.

I have searched the Internet, but somehow searching for this problem is really really hard. It gives me very general instructions about how to drag and drop and such. Very frustrating.

UPDATE

I have 4 windows on 4 workspaces, approx 5 tabs each. Two of the windows work normally, two of them have this error. If I open a new window it works normally. So some kind of event may make some of my windows buggy.

[image: Document dragging appears]

Comment: Roughly how many tabs do you have open, and how much relocating do you do?  Dragging still works for me in v66 on Ubuntu 18.04.  However, when I have a lot of tabs open, it often won't let me drag a tab (possibly a memory limitation?).  Also, if I start doing tons of tab relocations, it can get squirrelly.

Comment: @fixer1234 See UPDATE

Comment: How much RAM does the system have?  Do you normally have other big apps open at the same time?

Comment: 16GB RAM. Sometimes I compile big C++ projects then the system starts to do some swapping for a while but nothing dies and nothing becomes unstable. I have 16GB swap. Less than 10 percent is used. Normally I use less than half of the RAM when not compiling.

Comment: Sounds like it's something else.  Are you using the standard Firefox from the Ubuntu repository, one from snap or ftatpak, or downloading from the Mozilla site?  Have you tried exorcism?  :-)  A test to try: When you can't drag and drop, can you move tabs via keyboard shortcut?  (Move Right = Ctrl+Shift+PgDn. Move Left =  Ctrl+Shift+PgUp.)

Comment: @fixer1234 Very standard Firefox: `66.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`. Restarting Firefox makes the problem disappear, but it reappears after a while. I don't have the problem in this exact moment, but I will try the shortcuts as soon as I will have it.